# Ruby code to JAR

Tags: java, ruby, jar, jruby

I'd like to be able to compile a ruby program to a java JAR program. I've looked into JRuby and seen several examples of Java applications that would be able to eval() ruby code, but is there a more elegant solution allowing to simply code everything in ruby and then compile the lot directly to a JAR file?

The overall goal behind that is to be able to extend a security tool called Burp Proxy. So I'd like to be able to use all my Ruby pentesting scripts (obviously organising them so they interface with Burp extender) and compile my plugins to JAR file that can be executed by the tool.

If you could include some examples or links to examples in your answer that would even be better!

Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

JRuby allows you to compile to .class files, which you can jar up normally.  You'll just have to include jruby.jar as well.  From [here](http://kenai.com/projects/jruby/pages/JRubyCompiler#Ahead-Of-Time_(AOT)_Compilation):

> The typical way to run the AOT
>   compiler is to run
>
> `jrubyc <script name>`
>
> Or, on Microsoft Windows:
>
> `jruby -S jrubyc <script name>`
>
> This command outputs a .class file in
>   the current directory with parent
>   directories and package matching where
>   the file lives. So the following
>   command
>
> `jrubyc foo/bar/test.rb`
>
> will output
>
> `foo/bar/test.class`
>
> To run the file produced by the
>   compiler, use the -cp (class
>   searchpath) parameter with both the
>   current directory (parent directory
>   for foo/bar/test.class above) and the
>   path to jruby.jar, and execute it as
>   you would a normal Java class named
>   foo.bar.test:
>
> `java -cp .:/path/to/jruby.jar
>   foo.bar.test`