# Java compatible REST client in Ruby

Tags: java, ruby, rest, jruby, client-library

I need to create a client library to access a REST-based web service via HTTPS.

Not being overly familiar with Java, I would like to do this in Ruby, and then compile to a jar.

The payload I will send will be (in JSON) something like:

```
{
  "api-token": "12345",
  "org_number": 5,
  "name": "ABC corp",
  "users": {
    "employee_number": 1,
    "name": "bob jones",
    "email": "bob@abc.com"
  }
}
```

I assume the client library will need to:

- Initialize a new API interface instance with API token
- Give the instance organization information and set of users
- Tell the instance to serialize the organization and users to JSON, and POST to the webservice /org/new

So my question is:

- How do I structure my Ruby classes to produce an interface a Java programmer will be comfortable with (something like http://twitter4j.org/en/code-examples.html for example)

Comment: I recently wrote a REST client in Java for use at work. I can give you some code if you want to try to modify it to your needs.

Comment: Thanks for the offer Dan.  Unfortunately I'm not very knowledgeable about Java and will have to support the app, so would prefer to write something in Ruby and convert to Java

Comment: I can't assist too much in writing the REST portion in Ruby, but as for compiling it as a jar, take a look at jruby.org. Also see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1169674/ruby-code-to-jar

Comment: Here's a REST client written in Ruby you might want to look at: https://github.com/archiloque/rest-client

Comment: Thanks, but thats a library/gem that handles restful posts, gets etc.  What I'm interested in is creating a library that handles all that logic, like the twitter gem or the twitter4j

Comment: what do you mean with "convert to java"? if you use jruby you can run your ruby code directly on the jvm and still use whatever ruby gems you need for the REST communication. (I have been satisfied with the gem httparty for this on earlier occasions.)

Comment: I need to provide a stand-alone jar file that Java developers can require

Comment: JRuby is your best bet since it can create Java class files out of your ruby code, then you can create your jar from that. You just have to include the JRuby jar along with your library when you do that.

Answer (score 3):

Have you considered JRuby?

https://github.com/jruby/jruby/wiki

Comment: I have, the issue is this will be used in client libraries, and I don't want people to have to install JRuby to use it.  Compilation to JAR via JRuby is fine

Answer (score 0):

Have u heard of [ApiClient](https://github.com/zertico/api-client/)?

It works well inside rails, making your controller as much thin as possible. But it also works on a non rails application.

It raises different exceptions for each type of http code response to make easy for u to control the client logic based on the server responses.

It automatically initializes an object using the api response for you and sends all the requests by json as well.

It still in development, so let me know of any feature u may need.

I use it to access an API which requires a token for OAUTH2 and it works pretty well so far.

Hope u enjoy. =)